# Normal subgroups vs characteristic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, characteristic-subgroups

It is well known that characteristic subgroups of a group $G$ are normal. Is the converse true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The converse is wrong. Two counterexamples :

1) Let $G$ be the finite group of quaternions (of order $8$). Each subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ is normal but not characteristic.

2) Let $G$ be a vector space. Since $G$ is commutative, each of his subspaces are normal subgroups, but any non-trivial one is clearly not characteristic.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest example is the Klein four-group, which you can think of as a direct sum of two cyclic groups of order two, say $A\oplus B$.  Because it is abelian, all of its subgroups are normal.  However, there is an automorphism which interchanges the two direct summands $A$ and $B$, which shows that $A$ (and $B$) are normal, but not characteristic.  (In fact, the other non-trivial proper subgroup, generated by the product of the generators of $A$ and $B$ also works.)

Answer (score 0):

No. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup) gives $S_3 \times C_2$ ($C_2$ being the cycling group of order 2) as an example--the center isn't a characteristic subgroup.

Comment: The centre of any group is characteristic! The first factor $S_3$ in the direct product is normal but not characteristic.

Comment: You missed the word “fully” in that certainly confusing Wikipedia article.